# Draw outline only on current square

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am generating a map using a `for` loop in a different component, and this component is supposed to draw an outline ONLY on the square that was pressed last. Instead what I'm getting is that the previous square is not losing the redrawn outline. Your help is appreciated, thank you.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './MapStyles.css';

interface Props {
    terrainType: string
    x: number
    y: number
}

//let activeSquare: HTMLElement | null = null; //make it instead a set state deconstructor
//let previousSquare: HTMLElement | null = null;

let oldElement: HTMLElement;

export default function TerrainSquareStat({terrainType, x, y}: Props) {
    const [activeSquare, setActiveSquare] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
    
    function SelectSquare(e: React.MouseEvent) {
        
        const element = e.target as HTMLElement;
        
        setActiveSquare(element);

        if (activeSquare === element ) {
            console.log('first condition');
                activeSquare.style.border = 'none';
                activeSquare.style.zIndex = '0';
                setActiveSquare(null);
                console.log('3rd if');
            } else if (activeSquare === null ) {

                element.style.border = 'thin solid black';
                element.style.zIndex = '12';

                oldElement = element;
                setActiveSquare(element);
                console.log(element);
            } else {

            activeSquare.style.border = 'none';
            activeSquare.style.zIndex = '0';
            console.log('else if');
        }
        
}
    
    return (<div className={`square ${x.toString() + '-' + y.toString()}`}  id={`${terrainType}`} key= 'test' onMouseDown={e => SelectSquare(e)}></div>);
}
```

Comment: Is each square maintaining its own "active" state? You will probably need to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to have a single source of truth and pass in some `isActive` prop to each `TerrainSquareStat` component so it can match itself for the active status.

Comment: Hey there again @DrewReese, I appreciate the reply. I busted my head over this for a while, but the documentation wasn't enough for me to figure out my specific use case. Gonna try to give it a go again tomorrow perhaps. But so far, I've been struggling with the conditionals, and I'm not entirely sure if that's the correct or most efficient way to go about it, but hopefully I'll figure it out soon. Thank you again

Comment: Hi, if you can create a *running* codesandbox example of your code and share a link to it in your question I can take a look. If you're using github you can directly import it into a new sandbox workspace.

Comment: Hello @DrewReese really appreciate the help, you can find the full code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hellman-363hl?file=/src/Map/MapStyles.css